# Azure Logic App SubscriptionNotFound error

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

With the intention of building a generic logic app solution via Azure Portal, I've supplied all config to the logic app connectors as parameters sourced from a database.

The only problem I've experienced now though, is that the custom value supplied as the subscription for the ADF pipeline run is not working. The exact same value works when selected explicitly from the dropdown. The other values such as the Resource Group, Data Factory Name and the Data Factory Pipeline Name work fine when populated by the parameters.

Is there a specific way to do this? Or is this a bug in the Logic App ADF connector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do not put the name of subscription into the `Subscription` input box, it can not be executed success. You can put the subscription id into the `Subscription` input box, show as below screenshot:

[image]